# Какие операции разрешены внутри шаблонного метода?

Tags: java, generics

Предположим, у нас есть параметризованный класс с методом `someMethod`:

```
public class Example<X> {
    public void someMethod(Object obj) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Какие операции разрешены внутри метода? ("Разрешены" = "Компилятор скомпилирует")

- Проверка (`obj instanceof X`)
- Создание экземпляра `X`
- Приведение `obj` к типу `X`
- Получение экземпляра `Optional<x>` через `Optional.empty()`
- Проверка (`obj instanceof Optional<x>`)
- Создание массива `X`

Comment: что мешает просто взять и проверить самому?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В java есть такое понятие, как [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Дженерики в виде `<T>` существуют только до этапа компиляции, при компиляции `<T>` превратится просто в Object (или чуть более специфичный тип), верность типа передаваемого аргумента проверяется на этапе компиляции. Поэтому создать экземпляр X не получится - java в рантайме просто не знает, что это за X. Однако есть хак, позволяющий обойти это ограничение путем передачи используемого дженериком класса:

```
class Example<X> {

    private final Class<X> type;

    public Example(Class<X> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            type.getConstructor().newInstance();
            //...

    }
}
```

Более правильным решением, конечно, будет передавать некоторую *фабрику* Х, которая будет их штамповать, и не мучаться с конструкторами.

В то же время, с подобным классом:

```
class CustomCollection extends ArrayList<String> {}
```

все должно быть в порядке.

Все остальное, насколько понимаю, разрешено (единственное, что Optional можно будет проверить на то, является ли он инстансом `Optional`, а не `Optional<X>`; массив, если я правильно помню, надо будет кастовать из `Object[]`), хотя здесь еще недостаточно плавал и могу ошибаться.